# Table too wide, want to put it in another page

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [table too wide for twocolumn-mode document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82938/table-too-wide-for-twocolumn-mode-document)

I'm writing a two-column style conference paper, and I am having a table that's too wide to fit into a single column. I saw there are some related discussions on the forum, but I don't want to use `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` since I just have that much data to show (some high precision digits have to be shown in one table). I don't want to rotate it 90 degrees either.

Is it possible to just put it into its own page? Just like figures do. I know I can add a pair of `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` just for layout but it will mess up `caption` and `ref`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). `\begin{table}...\end{table}`?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am doing right now. It currently mess up with my two-column text.

Comment: Ok, I would recommend that you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Is your table too wide for just a single column, or even if it spans both columns?

Comment: It spans to both column so overlap with text and other tables. I will setup MWE later, but for now I just want to know is it possible to make it like a figure that will be put into its own page. Is there any keywords I can lookup for this?

Comment: If you use the `table*` environment (so that it spans over two columns without overlapping with text), is the output acceptable? If still needed, you can then put the figure on its own page by adding the optional `[p]` at the beginning of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `table*` seems to be what you are after

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}%[pb]
  \centering
  This would be a table in a real paper!
\caption{A big table}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Using the optional argument (which I've commented out) will all the table to go an a page of it's own, should that be what you want.

Comment: I've changed the `center` to `\centering`; I kindly suggest reading l2tabu-en, section 3.1

Comment: @MartinSchröder There should be no problem with `center` here: it's a demo, so that along with the text should be deleted in a real case. I would not use either here in a real table: centring float content should be done in the preamble.