# table too wide for twocolumn-mode document

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table which comes outside the text column width into the margin of the paper. How do I make the text in the table align to left ?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

 \begin{abstract}
 abc
\end{abstract}

\section{table}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Top 5 movies recommended by content-based CF algorithm} %title of the table
\centering
% centering table
\begin{tabular}{c r}
% creating eight columns
\hline\hline
%inserting double-line
Movies&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Genre} \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
% inserts single-line
The Flintstones(1994)
& Children's,Comedy\\
% Entering row contents
Son in Law(1974) & Comedy, Horror\\
The Princess Bride(1987) & Action, Adventure, Comedy, Romance\\
Star Wars(1977) & Action, Adventure, Romance, Sci-Fi, War\\
Toy Story(1995)
& Animated, Animated Children's, Comedy\\[1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline
% inserts single-line
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:hresult}
\end{table}
 \end{document}


 This is how it looks :
```

[image]

Comment: You probably just need to add `\noindent`. But, can you _please_start including afully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, as opposed to code snippets.   Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: sorry, did the editing

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So, what is the problem. Are you saying the table is too far to the right of the margin? If so, replace the `\centering` with a `\noindent`.

Comment: To economize on the table's width, I suggest replacing `\begin{tabular}{c r}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{}c r@{}}`. By the way, when I compile your MWE, the width of the table does *not* exceed the `\textwidth` parameter.

Comment: As Mico pointed out, the table width looks fine. You can use `\usepackage{showframe}` to see the page margin.

Comment: You will not be able to see the problem right away unless you have text in two columns. The table goes outside the text columns towards the edges of the paper, mainly because there is too much text in each row

Comment: \noindent in place of \centering does not work and neither does \begin{tabular}{@{}c r@{}}

Comment: But you example given is not two columns?  Can you please provide a complete example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Yes that is because my file is big and I just copied the table data into new file. Check the picture I uploaded - the table crosses the bounds of text columns

Comment: @princessofpersia - if two-column mode is an important part of your document, then you should include this feature in your MWE.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to latex and was not sure what all elements are crucial to my document.

Answer (score 14):

Since you use two-column mode, you should use a `table*` rather than a `table` environment. The `table*` environment spans both columns. A restriction is that these floats can only appear at the top of a page.

[image]

By the way, I suggest you use the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` of the `booktabs` package in the `tabular` environment, rather than `\hline` and various ad-hoc vertical spacing commands. The following modified form of your MWE shows how these commands may be used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5] % filler text
\begin{table*}
\caption{Top 5 movies recommended by content-based CF algorithm} \label{tab:hresult}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
Movies & Genre \\ 
\midrule
The Flintstones (1994) & Children's, Comedy\\
Son in Law (1974) & Comedy, Horror\\
The Princess Bride (1987) & Action, Adventure, Comedy, Romance\\
Star Wars (1977) & Action, Adventure, Romance, Sci-Fi, War\\
Toy Story (1995) & Animated, Animated Children's, Comedy\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[6-14] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I increased the amount of filler text to show the two column output below that table, and added the image.

Comment: @PeterGrill - Many thanks for editing my MWE and for providing the image. That was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 8):

Here are a bunch of different options for your table:

1. Your original table with `\centering`.
2. With `\noindent` (which aligns it with the left margin), and column specification of `{@{}c r@{}}` which remove the column padding before the first column and after the last column.
3. All column spacing removed with `{@{}c@{}r@{}}`, just to see the effect (probably not a good idea).
4. Using `{@{}c P{1.5in}@{}}` which removed the column spacing as per 2, but also uses the `p` column type for the second column to allow for paragraph wrapping.

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{}}%


\newcommand*{\MyTabular}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{#1}
% creating eight columns
\hline\hline
%inserting double-line
Movies&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Genre} \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
% inserts single-line
The Flintstones(1994)
& Children's, Comedy\\
% Entering row contents
Son in Law(1974) & Comedy, Horror\\
The Princess Bride(1987) & Action, Adventure, Comedy, Romance\\
Star Wars(1977) & Action, Adventure, Romance, Sci-Fi, War\\
Toy Story(1995)
& Animated, Animated Children's, Comedy\\[1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline % inserts single-line
\end{tabular}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]% Keep effect of \centering localized
\centering 
\MyTabular{c r}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\noindent % 
\MyTabular{@{}c r@{}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\noindent % 
\MyTabular{@{}c@{}r@{}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\noindent % 
\MyTabular{@{}c P{1.5in}@{}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```