# wide table in a two-column document

Tags: tables, lyx, two-column

I have a two-column LyX document. I want to add a table that will be as wide as the entire page, so that it will not have to be squeezed into a single column. I found some suggestions: [table too wide for twocolumn-mode document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82938/table-too-wide-for-twocolumn-mode-document) [Page-wide table in two-column mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode) , however, I have no idea how to implement them in LyX...

Comment: You can use the `table*` environment that uses the full width, and will float its contents at the top of a following page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LyX knows already about that problem. Open the float settings (e.g. by right click on "float: Table" and choose "Settings...") and select "Span columns". The float will be called "float: Table*" now (note the star).

This works also for other floats (e.g. Figure).

Comment: I wonder how this can be assigned by default to a custom float definition for a custom LyX layout file.

Comment: This solution always pushes the table to the absolute bottom of the page or absolute top of the page (at least with RevTeX 4). When clicking "span columns" I can no longer click on "here definitely", for example. How can I force the page-wide table to appear somewhere in the middle instead of the bottom or top?

Comment: @user1271772: By removing the `[h]`. https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12214.